# How to merge cells with the same content in table component?

Tags: html-table

If there are multiple consecutive cells of the same data in a certain column of the table, these cells will be automatically merged and the content will be displayed in the center. How to achieve this effect on the table component?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJaC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) `rowspan` attribute. The code example is taken from the same link:

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
  padding: 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

th[scope='col'] {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: #fff;
}

th[scope='row'] {
  background-color: #d7d9f2;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    Alien football stars
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Player</th>
    <th scope="col">Gloobles</th>
    <th scope="col">Za'taak</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
    <td rowspan="2">7</td> <!--  -->
    <td>4,569</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
    <td>7,223</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>6,219</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```